# PayPal error handling. No handler found for post message ack for message postrobot_method

Tags: reactjs, paypal, error-handling

I have a misunderstanding about using a PayPal [react bindings](https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/docs/frameworks.md#reactjs-element) of checkout component.

My payment function:

```
  let payment = () => {

        return new paypal.Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            await appStore.payment.paypalCreatePayments();

            if (!appStore.payment.paymentsError && appStore.payment.paypalToken.payment.id) {
                resolve(appStore.payment.paypalToken.payment.id);
            } else {
                reject(appStore.payment.paymentsError);
                alert('Payment failure! error:', appStore.payment.paymentsError);
            }
        });
    };
```

and Button component:

```
        PayPalButton = paypal.Button.driver('react', { React, ReactDOM });
        <PayPalButton
            client={client}
            payment={payment}
            commit={true}
            env='sandbox'
            onAuthorize={onAuthorize}
            onCancel={onCancel}
            onError={onError}
        />;
```

onAuthorize function:

```
onAuthorize = async (data, actions) => {
    await appStore.payment.paypalExecutePayments({
        paymentID: data.paymentID,
        payerID: data.payerID,
        keys: appStore.payment.paypalToken.keys
    });

    actions.close();

    if (!appStore.payment.paymentsError) {
        this.props.paymentSuccess();
    } else {
        this.props.paymentFailure(appStore.payment.paymentsError);
    }
};
```

And it works fine when all goes ok. But when I get an error from my server side (e.g. 404 or 500) Paypal throws this error message:

```
Uncaught Error: No handler found for post message ack for message: postrobot_method from https://1b375a11.ngrok.io in https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/button
```

Any ideas how this error can be handled?

Comment: Can you share your `onAuthorize` function?

Comment: @Scott done. But I think this error throws before calling onAuthorize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No handler means that the paypal button is rendered before the paypal checkout script is fully loaded.